# db2 applying licensing file produces two licenses

Tags: db2, db2-luw, license

1. I installed Db2 from fixpack v11.5.7.0 using `db2_install` command.
2. I have downloaded "IBM Db2 Advanced Edition - VPC Option V11.5.6 - Activation (CC9WHML)" file from IBM Passport Advantage.
3. I have applied license with: `db2licm -a <license_file>`
4. I have checked applied license: `db2licm -l` and output is:

```
Product name:                     "DB2 Community Edition"
License type:                     "Community"
Expiry date:                      "Permanent"
Product identifier:               "db2dec"
Version information:              "11.5"
Max amount of memory (GB):        "16"
Max number of cores:              "4"
Features:
IBM DB2 Performance Management Offering:              "Not licensed"

Product name:                     "DB2 Advanced Edition"
License type:                     "Virtual Processor Core"
Expiry date:                      "Permanent"
Product identifier:               "db2adv"
Version information:              "11.5"
Enforcement policy:               "Hard Stop"
Features:
IBM DB2 Performance Management Offering:              "Not licensed"
```

I haven't seen this kind of display before. Looks like two licenses are applied "Community" and "Advance" edition.

**Questions:**

a) Is it OK that two licenses are displayed? Which one is valid, both?

b) At "Advanced" edition section what does "Enforcement policy" of "Hard Stop" relates to? Until now I have always seen only "Soft Stop". Like I see "Advance" edition has no CPU cores limitations, so what does "Hard Stop" means at this license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same thing and I guess that the licence for the community edition is applied always, just in case. In the deploy job, I just remove that one before adding the one that I'm entitled to:

```
db2licm -r db2dec
db2licm -a <licence>
```

I don't think it matters (but I don't know for sure) that the community edition is there. AFAIK, there are no complaints from the compliance report:

```
db2licm -g <filename>
```

if you have both. It is however more convenient - for me - if there is one licence on each server (I collect that and other info from all servers on a regular basis and create a report out of it).

A hard stop usually means that things will stop working if you violate the licence. If you for example use any functionality from the "IBM DB2 Performance Management Offering" you probably will notice. A soft stop usually means you will get noticed of the violation, but things will continue to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After installing Db2 from fixpack I have checked the license with "db2licm -l" command and there was "Community Edition" and after applied "Advanced Edition" I have got two licenses displayed. Excellent, now I have removed the "Community Edition" license. Thanks.

What about "Hard Stop" part of the license? Why is there Hard Stop?

Comment: I added my beliefs about hard stop vs soft stop. If you want to be absolutely sure, check with your sales rep.

Comment: Yes, hard stop should return error if some feature is used that is not extra licensed. According to the documentation from HARD to SOFT can be changed with `db2licm -e db2adv SOFT` and when checking it with `db2licm -l` and there is still "Hard Stop" for Enforcement Policy.

Comment: Interesting, I tried that as well and recycled the instance but it still says "Hard Stop". @data_henrik has a blog entry from 2015:  https://blog.4loeser.net/2015/ where he mentions the -e flag, but there is no db2licm -l after applying SOFT, so I don't know if this is normal.